Angular - Module Federation - How to Share model/usecase files
I'm working with Module federation and I've a shell app and a host app. They are linked as follows:
Shell Application:

webpack.config.js

plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      remotes: {
        // no need to declare remotes as they are dynamically loaded.
      },
      shared: {
        ...shareAll({
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: false,
          requiredVersion: "auto",
          eager: true
        }),
      },
    }),
  ],


landingPage.component.ts

private async loadMfe1Async(): Promise<void> {
    if (!this._mfe1ViewContainerRef) {
      return;
    }
    this._mfe1ViewContainerRef.clear();
    const loadRemoteWebpackModuleOptions: LoadRemoteModuleOptions = {
      type: 'module',
      exposedModule: './my-standalone-component',
      remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js',
    };
    const webpackModule: any = await loadRemoteModule(loadRemoteWebpackModuleOptions);
    this._mfe1ViewContainerRef.createComponent(webpackModule.MyStandaloneComponent);
  }


landingPage.component.html

<div class="landing-wrapper">
  Shell Application: {{version}}
  <ng-container #mfe1></ng-container>
</div>

Host Application:

webpack.config.js

const {
  shareAll,
  withModuleFederationPlugin,
} = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "mfe1-ng16",
  filename: "remoteEntry.js", // this doesn't need to be set, if not specified it defaults to remoteEntry.js. Setting it here just for demo purposes.
  exposes: {
    "./my-standalone-component": "./src/app/my-standalone-component/my-standalone-component.component.ts",
  },
  shared: {
    ...shareAll({
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: false,
      requiredVersion: "auto",
    }),
  },
});

Now, I have 2 questions:

Suppose I've a file called wallet.model.ts in the shell application with the following data:
export interface WalletModel {
currency: string;
amount: number;
}


How do I use this Wallet Model interface in the host application?

If I have the same wallet.model.ts file in the host application, How do I use that in the shell application?


Are both projects part of the same repository?

You should be able to share resources between the projects by exporting them and adding them in the main tsconfig.json in the project root.
Maybe you can define a index.ts where you export everything you want to share between the applications.
tsconfig.json in project root:
{
...
  "paths": {
      "@shell": ["/projects/shell/src/index.ts"]
  }
}
...

index.ts in the Shell application src folder:
export * from './app/wallet.model';

This allows you to access the export elements by importing them in your components:
import { Wallet } from '@shell';

This solution takes for granted that the two applications share the same repository/directory.
I've also created a working GitHub test application if you wanna try this out!
